# Does running remove(int index) method on a list to remove object instance invoke garbage collection?

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, garbage-collection

I am writing an app on Android - part of this involves some enemies on the screen. These are all contained in an ArrayList.
My code determines whether an instance of the Enemy class is outside the screen. If so, it then needs to delete the instance of the object to preserve resources as these can be spawned at a fairly high rate. I currently invoke the

```
remove(int index)
```

method to remove elements from the List. Will this also engage garbage collection on the elements? If not, how can I ensure garbage collection (or is it not worth it?)

Comment: It's not worth it. Android will call the GC for you.

Comment: Removed objects will get garbage collected eventually; when or how this happens is up to the JVM to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, it then needs to delete the instance of the object to preserve resources as these can be spawned at a fairly high rate

More likely, it needs to maintain an [object pool](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html) of these objects, to "preserve resources" if "these can be spawned at a fairly high rate".

> Will this also engage garbage collection on the elements?

No. Garbage collection generally is performed asynchronously. Once you have no more references to an object, it will be *eligible* for garbage collection, but removing references does not *cause* garbage collection.

> If not, how can I ensure garbage collection

You don't.

Comment: It is good that you mentioned the object pool pattern. If the game is simple to the point where you just spawn enemies and give them x, y, deltaX, deltaY values and let them go out of the screen, just resetting x, y and (optionally) reworking those deltas should solve the problem.

Comment: @mafagafogigante: Agreed. Object pools are popular in game development for just this reason. Android uses them too, in other areas (e.g., `SensorEvent` objects are pooled).

Comment: I like that object pool idea a lot actually. Shall definitely implement that.